# How to get resharper to skip generated files

Tags: resharper

Resharper really complains about files such as reference.cs that is generated by things like WCF service reference.  How do I get Resharper to skip such files entirely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. menu `ReSharper -> Options`
2. `Code inspection -> Settings` item
3. button `Edit items to skip`

Comment: The one negative seems to be this has to be done explicitly for each reference.cs file ... I can't see anyway to say "always ignore reference.cs files"

Comment: I'm having the same problem with my WCF data service generated file. Something like 5k warnings in it. This should be simpler to do than it is.

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work by entering `Referen?e.cs` into the ReSharper *Generated file masks* list. Apparently the presence of the `?` wildcard tricked it into applying to all `Reference.cs` files (well, remember that it will get files named `Referente.cs` too, but I can live with that.